# Как искать по сконкатенированной ячейке?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

К примеру в базе есть 2 поля - code1, code2. Могут быть от 1 до 3 символов.
У меня есть составной код, т.е. code1 + code2. И я не могу восстановить из этой строки 2 кода, т.е. мне надо искать как-то так -

```
WHERE (`code1``code2`) = $code1and2
```

Как это делается? 
А если кто знает, как такое сделать с использованием ActiveRecord Yii - будет шикарно.

Comment: В mysql строки объединяются функцией concat, т.е. `where concat(code1, code2)=...`

Comment: Спасибо, не подумал, что ими можно свойства объединять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для конкатенации строк в MySQL используется функция [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

`CONCAT(str1,str2,...)`

Но есть одно но - если вы используете выражения, проводящие операции над записями в условии WHERE, то mysql придется просчитывать это выражение для каждой записи в таблице, а потом только фильтровать. Индекс использоваться в таком случае не будет, и при большом количестве записей в таблице такой запрос может работать очень медленно.

Лучше все-таки каким-то образом разделить строку, по которой вы хотите фильтровать записи, и искать по каждому полю отдельно. Либо же добавить поле, содержащее полную строку, и создать для него индекс.